# I don't understand what's going on this syntax javascript

Tags: javascript, assignment-operator, destructuring

How gonna assign in `const { Types, Creators }` in the below code I mean what **Types** gonna hold and what **Creators** gonna hold.

```
   const { Types, Creators } = createActions({
        userRequest: ['username'],
        userSuccess: ['avatar'],
        userFailure: null
    })



var createActions = (function (config, options) {
  if (R.isNil(config)) {
    throw new Error('an object is required to setup types and creators');
  }
  if (R.isEmpty(config)) {
    throw new Error('empty objects are not supported');
  }

  return {
    Types: convertToTypes(config, options),
    Creators: convertToCreators(config, options)
  };
})
```

Comment: Whatever type convertToTypes(config, options), and convertToCreators(config, options) returns

Comment: Learn about destructuring.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is object destructuring assignment. `Types` and `Creators` will be defined as the `Types` and `Creators` properties returned from the object returned at `createActions()` call. For example

```js
const {Types, Creators} = (() => {
  return {Types:0, Creators:1}
})();

console.log(Types, Creators)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), It looks at the returned object and assigns the correct key to the variable. Think of it as shorthand for:

```
const createActions = (function (config, options) {
  if (R.isNil(config)) {
    throw new Error('an object is required to setup types and creators');
  }
  if (R.isEmpty(config)) {
    throw new Error('empty objects are not supported');
  }

  return {
    Types: convertToTypes(config, options),
    Creators: convertToCreators(config, options)
  };
})

let results = createActions({
        userRequest: ['username'],
        userSuccess: ['avatar'],
        userFailure: null
    }),
    Types = results.Types,
    Creators = results.Creators;
```